# Why is ListObject autopopulating formula with absolute cell references instead of looping through code?

Tags: excel, vba, loops, array-formulas

I have a Named Table (ListObject) that I am trying to populate with a formula using a loop function.  In my table, I have a price in column D and blank cells in columns "E:P", representing the months of the year.  These columns are for user input.

I would like columns "Q:AB" to be populated with the product of the price and the # of product for each month to give total cost for each month and this can be changed if the user changes any values in columns "E:P".  For instance, an output vba formula for "Q2" should be "$D2*E2".  And then it would calculate this for each row containing a price (usually ten rows with each row being a different price).

I am not sure why but my output cells ("Q2:AB10") are all exactly the same :  "$D$2*$E$2"

I have tried using ranges instead of cell.addresses but (possibly because of the variables I am trying to loop?) I kept getting Error 1004.  This code runs but it doesn't seem to be changing the output even as it is looping through.  The specific code I am working with looks like this:

```
With Worksheets (i) 'this is defined farther up in the sub
  lrow2 = .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row 'find last row
  col = Range("D" & lrow2).Column 'find correct column

'Confirm cells' address reference correct cells
  Debug.Print (Cells(lrow2 + 1, 4).Address)
  Debug.Print (Cells(lrow2 + 1, col + 1).Address)
  Debug.Print (Cells(lrow2 + 1, col + 13).Address)

For c = col  To col + 12
  Cells(lrow2 + 1, c + 13).Formula = "=" & Cells(lrow2 + 1, 4).Address & "*" & Cells(lrow2 + 1, c + 1).Address
Next c
```

I need the code to be dynamic to accept additional rows (10 rows at a time) but the columns will remain the same, I am just not experienced enough to know the best way to approach this.

Comment: Sine you are using a `With` statement, you should use `.Cells(lrow2 + 1, c + 13)` and not ` Cells(lrow2 + 1, c + 13)`. Also after `Address` add `(False, False, xlA1)` so you won't get the absolute reference.

Comment: I did try running it with .Cells but it doesn't change the result I get

Comment: Try the code in my answer below

Comment: Ahh adding the False, False, xlA1 did the trick.  Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To learn more about `Range.Address` property see this link:

[Range.Address property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.address)

Modify:

```
Cells(lrow2 + 1, c + 13).Formula = "=" & Cells(lrow2 + 1, 4).Address & "*" & Cells(lrow2 + 1, c + 1).Address
```

With:

```
.Cells(lrow2 + 1, c + 13).Formula = "=" & .Cells(lrow2 + 1, 4).Address(False, True, xlA1) & "*" & .Cells(lrow2 + 1, c + 1).Address(False, False, xlA1)
```